# how to group MySql rows based on month?

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

I've a table with a datetime (format: 'Y-m-d H:i:s') 'created' field and 'amount' (integer) field in each row. Now I want to find out month wise total 'amount' in last year. How can I do this?

**EDIT**

I made an edit to clarify the actual problem. so basically I want to know total 'amount' in each month, but only for the last year.

**EDIT2**

Last year means last 365 days. So somewhere I've to consider 'current day'?

**EDIT3**

My bad, actually last year is last 12 months. So number of days would be between 336 and 365.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this (updated to answer your "edit3"):

```
SELECT
    YEAR(created) as year,
    MONTH(created) AS month,
    SUM(amount) AS total_amount
FROM table1
WHERE created
    BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL (DAY(NOW()) - 1) DAY - INTERVAL 11 MONTH
    AND NOW()
GROUP BY YEAR(created), MONTH(created)
ORDER BY YEAR(created), MONTH(created);
```

Example result (when run in April 2010):

```
year  month  total_amount
2009  5      26
2010  1      20
```

Note also that months with no entries will not be returned at all (rather than being returned with total_amount = 0).

Test data:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (created datetime NOT NULL, amount INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO table1 (created, amount) VALUES
('2010-01-01 13:56:23', 5),
('2010-01-04 13:56:23', 15),
('2009-05-04 13:56:23', 26);
```

Comment: @Mark Byers: If last year is considered period between current day and last 365 days, then what changes would be required?

Comment: @understack: `WHERE created BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 365 DAY) AND NOW()`. Also consider using `INTERVAL 1 YEAR` instead of  `INTERVAL 365 DAY` if that's what you actually mean.

Comment: @Mark Byers: could you please suggest the changes for my EDIT3? Thanks.

Comment: @understack: I don't understand your edit3. How do you get 336 days?

Comment: actually the last month could be in its first day, so I subtracted 30 days. So I've to consider last 12 months. Last month would be considered a complete month independent of how many days have passed. So in today situation - April would be considered a full month. And then 11 previous months.

Comment: @understack: I just realized that in my answer the first month could have had some or all of the first day missing, depending on when the query was run. I have fixed it now by adding a call to DATE.

Answer (score 2):

This returns the count and total amount for last year:

```
SELECT MONTH(created) as month_updated,
  COUNT(created) as month_updates, SUM(amount) as month_total FROM table
WHERE created BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR) AND NOW()
GROUP BY MONTH(created)
```

Or, if you specifically mean just 2009:

```
SELECT MONTH(created) as month_updated,
  COUNT(created) as month_updates, SUM(amount) as month_total FROM table
WHERE created BETWEEN '2009-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2009-12-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY MONTH(created)
```

Comment: Awesome query sir. +1 from my side. It worked in my case, now i can found the total amount individual month wise.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(some_row) AS or_whatever FROM your_table GROUP BY MONTH(update);
```

To be more specific (with your update):

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table_name GROUP BY MONTH(created);
```